# In a bash script what is the difference between ${VAR:-...} and ${VAR:?...}

Tags: bash

I'm following [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_03.html) tutorial on transformation of variables.

If I have the following:

```
echo ${TEST:-test} #TEST is undefined, 'test' is printed and TEST is still undefined.
echo ${FOO:?"some text"} #"some text" is printed and FOO is still undefined.
```

What is the difference between the `':-'` and the `':?'` above?

Comment: You have your answer here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are testing shortcuts:

```
 echo ${TEST:-test}
```

If `$TEST` exists then its value will be used, otherwise the value of `$test` will be used.  If you want `TEST` to be set then you probably need:

```
echo ${TEST:=test}
```

Next one:

```
echo ${FOO:?"some text"}
```

If `$FOO` is set then use its value, else output to `stderr` the error message "some text" (default is "parameter null or not set").

Comment: Slight correction: `:-` and `:=` will both use the alternate value if `TEST` is set, but to an empty string. `${TEST-test}` and `${TEST=test}` will preserve the empty string if that is what `TEST` was explicitly set to previously. `${FOO:?}` will likewise print the error message if `FOO` is set but to an empty string; use `${FOO?error}` if an empty value is valid.